# Wildcard 301 redirect using regular expression

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

Any help with this would be great as I am struggling to get this to work.

I am trying to do a wildcard RedirectMatch 301 redirect for `/pop.php?path=content/` using

```
RedirectMatch 301 /pop.php?path=content/.* http://mywebsite.com
```

But due to the ".", "?" and "=" is it not working correctly and I am not good with regular expressions.

Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a `.htaccess` file in your site root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} path=content [NC]
RewriteRule pop.php http://mywebsite.com/? [R=301,L]
```

You need the `RewriteCond` to inspect the value of the query string. If and only if it's a match, `pop.php` will be redirected to the other site.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tired the code you have supplied but i get a 404 rather than a 301 redirect to the root domain.Thanks Steve.

Comment: A 404 as in `pop.php` can't be found? Is it a physical file or virtual path?

Comment: The file no longer exists. The file was used in an old PHP gallery script was removed from the site. The full path is http://subdomain.websiteaddress.com/pop.php?path=content/path/path/host.jpg&margin=10&posx=301&posy=210&popdisplay=1,0,0,0,0,1,0&lang=lang.ini&col1=34507A&col2=BBC5D3

Comment: Do you have `mod_rewrite` enabled and did you put the `.htaccess` in the subdomain site root?

Comment: Mod_rewrite is enabled and .htaccess is included in the root of the sub domain. I have other rewrite rules running and working but just struggling to work this one out with some kind of wild card which will 301 redirect any /pop.php?path=content/ query to the root of the sub domain.

Comment: The only way you can get a 404 is if that rule's not matching, otherwise you'll get the 301 redirect. Maybe one of your other rules is conflicting?

Comment: ok thank you for your help i will check the rules again and try the code you have provided to me.